# Bootstrap Dropdown Expanded and will not close

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen several questions on here about when the dropdown will not open, or will not close after opening. My issue is that the dropdown-menu loads as open when the page loads. Here is a working copy of the code (http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/hts7F/), that I stumbled upon. I cannot get my menus to be closed by default. 
My relevant code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="includes/dropdownfix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
```

and

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact</a></li>
    <?php 
        if($profile_pic){
            echo"<img src=\"".$profile_pic."\" />";
        } 
    ?>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo"$name"; ?>
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="index.php">test</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Please help! Also I'm using bootstrap 3.3.5 I believe. Thanks

EDIT: My bad, heres dropdownfix.js, copied from http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/hts7F/.

```
// On dropdown open
$(document).on('shown.bs.dropdown', function(event) {
    var dropdown = $(event.target);

    // Set aria-expanded to true
    dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu').attr('aria-expanded', true);

    // Set focus on the first link in the dropdown
    setTimeout(function() {
        dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu li:first-child a').focus();
    }, 10);
});

// On dropdown close
$(document).on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(event) {
    var dropdown = $(event.target);

    // Set aria-expanded to false        
    dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu').attr('aria-expanded', false);

    // Set focus back to dropdown toggle
    dropdown.find('.dropdown-toggle').focus();
});
```

Comment: Include the code for dropdownfix.js

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with PHP?

Comment: @topher, I did on edit, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get something like this working?:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5u9o4vu/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="colapsableDropdown">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutus.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="index.php">test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If that still doesn't work, then i recommend you open your Developer Console (Your Browser Inspect Element option) and check it because you might have missing files.

Comment: Even when I try just this, the same thing happens. Menu is expanded by default and will not open/close on click. Theres no errors in the dev console...

Comment: It's certainly weird that having the core files for Bootstrap and jquery for them to work abd they do this. Have you checked removing any other js file laying around your index?

Comment: I have, and another weird thing is that on this example someone set up, http://www.bootply.com/b6Rr8K4Gke, the same error happens where it stays open.